# How to assert expected value should be greater, equal values to the actual value using Spark ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm writing Spark test application using scala test want to assert my expected result should be greater or equal to the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert (expected >= myMethod/*, "This is the first of the annoying tests"*/)
```